# Javascript - how to check if a value is only numeric and alphabatic numbers with no space

Tags: javascript

I have an input file that I want to make sure only accepts number and alphabet with no space. I used this

```
/[0-9]{0,}[A-zA-Z]^\S*$/.test(sValue)
```

but it does not cover all the cases. I was wondering if any one knows what am I missing.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are making it too complicated. You just need to anchor front and back (`^` and `$`)and then do case-insensitive match (`i`) to the set of alphanumeric characters with `/^[a-z0-9]+$/i`:

```js
// True
sValue = "123abc"
console.log(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(sValue))

sValue = "123"
console.log(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(sValue))

sValue = "abc"
console.log(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(sValue))

//False
sValue = "123abc "
console.log(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(sValue))

sValue = "123,hyg"
console.log(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(sValue))

sValue = " 123"
console.log(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(sValue))

// Unclear whether this should this be true or false?
sValue = ""
console.log(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(sValue))
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. If I want the last one to evaluate to false what should I add to the regex?

Comment: You don't have to do anything @WaterfrVilla -- it already evaluates as `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let sValue="word120";
 
let checker = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/g.test(sValue);

console.log(checker);
```